# Proper way to show server's RAM, CPU and GPU usage on react app

Tags: python, reactjs, algorithm, fastapi

I have a project in which the backend is written in FastAPI and the frontend uses React. My goal here is to add a component that will monitor some of the pc/server's performances in real time. Right now the project is still under development in local environment so basically I'll need to fetch the CPU/GPU usage and RAM (derived from my PC) from Python and then send them to my React app. My question here is, what is the cheapest way to accomplish this? Is setting an API and fetching a GET request every ten seconds a good approach or there're some better ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation & Tips:

I know EXACTLY what you're describing. I also made a mobile app using Flutter and Python. I have been trying to get multiple servers to host the API instead of one server. I personally think Node.Js is worth checking out since it allows clustering which is extremely powerful. If you want to stick with python, the best way to get memory usage in python is using psutil like this: `memory = psutil.virtual_memory().percent`, but for the CPU usage you would have to do some sort of caching or multi threading because you cannot get the CPU usage without a delay `cpu = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)`. If you want your API to be fast then the periodic approach is bad, it will slow down your server, also if you do anything wrong on the client side, you could end up DDOSing your API, which is an embarrassing thing that I did when I first published my app. The best approach is to only call the API when it is needed, and for example, flutter has cached widgets which was very useful, because I would have to fetch that piece of data only once every few hours.

Key Points:

-Only call the API when it is crucial to do so.

-Python cannot get the CPU usage in real-time.

-Node performed better than my Flask API (not FastAPI).

-Use client-side caching if possible.